# Exporting from phpmyadmin to sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, phpmyadmin, export

Wondering if it's a simple way to export my database in phpmyadmin into my local sql server 2012? I have never done that before, so very curious if and how that will be done.

Which type of file will it be exported from phpmyadmin ?

sql ?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try; although the two systems are different, they're both database servers that speak SQL. The resulting file may or may not load effortlessly (in theory, it should). From within phpMyAdmin, you'll go to the Export page of the database you wish to export. Select the "Custom" radio button and SQL as the file type (which is the default anyway, so there's nothing to change, just double-check it).

Now under the "Format-specific options" header, look for "Database system or older MySQL server to maximize output compatibility with:" and select MSSQL. Finish exporting the file and try importing it to your Microsoft SQL Server. In theory, the export will have changed all the specific commands so that your SQL Server can import it without any manual effort.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will take a look of how it will be done.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is you have to do a fair amount of fixing up, even if you select MSSQL compatibility. Things like invalid column types (bigint with lengths, longtext), invalid key definitions, backticks rather than quotes on column names (MSSQL compatibility changes the CREATE TABLE quoting but not the INSERT quoting, oddly - and you can turn off quoting altogether).

None of it insurmountable on small amounts of data, but a pain if you have a lot and/or care about exact reproduction of things like key structure (rather than just having a copy of the data to play with).

Some of this might be version dependent, but if you're using it on shared hosting then you're stuck with whatever they give you.